# how to sort a tableview cell alphabetically

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have date view cell that is been filled by an array, i need to add two buttons one for A to Z and other Z to A. I able to sort the array but not sure how to change it in runtime i mean in the table view pressing the buttons. This is te code i using to sort:

```
[filePathsArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

The table view is just regular table view been filed with an array from a csv file. This is how i get the array 
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSMutableArray*   fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
//--- Listing file by name sort
NSLog(@"\n File list %@",fileList);

//---- Sorting files by extension
NSMutableArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

[filePathsArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSLog(@"\n sort by");

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF EndsWith '.csv'"];
filePathsArray =  [filePathsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"\n\n Sorted files by extension %@",filePathsArray);
```

any help or orientation would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Assuming your datasource is done properly, just reload the cell(s) that needs to be updated. UITableView have a .reloadData() to reload the entire table, if only specific cells are affected you may instead use .reloadRows(at:with:) providing the indexPath of the cells you want to reload and one option of the enum UITableViewRowAnimation to select the visual effects of reloading those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sortUsingComparator` instead of `sortUsingSelector` to implement the different sorting directions:

```
[filePathsArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString* fp1, NSString* fp2) {
  return [fp1 compare:fp2];
}];
```

and to revert the sort direction, simply swap the parameters for `compare`:

```
[filePathsArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString* fp1, NSString* fp2) {
  return [fp2 compare:fp1];
}];
```

Your `A-Z` and `Z-A` buttons can then simply sort using one of those methods and call `[tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: HI! i use the code above but is crashing this i what i get in the console:
-[__NSArrayI sortUsingComparator:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c4649330
2018-01-16 16:12:03.305146-0700 oFiOSstoryboard[31492:4290430] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI sortUsingComparator:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c4649330'

Comment: Ah, that's most likely because `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath` returns a non-mutable array. Change the assignment to `filePathsArray` to this: `NSMutableArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil].mutableCopy`; (i.e., append .mutableCopy)